# How apply the imageBrush to the datagrid header background?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

May i know how to set the Datagrid Header background using the imagebrush? I know how method to set the background color (like the code snippet). But i need to know how about imagebrush? Any advice? Thanks

p/s: i found a [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721603/grid-background-image-using-imagebrush) here, but doesnt work.....

xaml code snippet:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
      </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean how to write the Setter, you could use [property element syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788723.aspx#property_element_syntax) for the `Setter.Value` property:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="..."/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```