# Slugs for SEO using PHP - Appending name to end of URL

Tags: php, redirect, url-rewriting, preg-replace, preg-match-all

**Something I have noticed on the StackOverflow website:**

If you visit the URL of a question on StackOverflow.com:

> ["https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721603"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721603)

The website adds the name of the question to the end of the URL, so it turns into:

> ["https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721603/grid-background-image-using-imagebrush"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721603/grid-background-image-using-imagebrush)

This is great, I understand that this makes the URL more meaningful and is probably good as a technique for SEO.

**What I wanted to Achieve after seeing this Implementation on StackOverflow**

I wish to implement the same thing with my website.  I am happy using a `header()` 301 redirect in order to achieve this, but I am attempting to come up with a tight script that will do the trick.

**My Code so Far**

[Please see it working by clicking here](http://tehplayground.com/#V4X7TIFKN)

```
// Set the title of the page article (This could be from the database).  Trimming any spaces either side
$original_name = trim(' How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python with-dash?');

// Replace any characters that are not A-Za-z0-9 or a dash with a space
$replace_strange_characters = preg_replace('/[^\da-z-]/i', " ", $original_name);

// Replace any spaces (or multiple spaces) with a single dash to make it URL friendly
$replace_spaces = preg_replace("/([ ]{1,})/", "-", $replace_strange_characters);

// Remove any trailing slashes
$removed_dashes = preg_replace("/^([\-]{0,})|([\-]{2,})|([\-]{0,})$/", "", $replace_spaces);

// Show the finished name on the screen
print_r($removed_dashes);
```

**The Problem**

I have created this code and it works fine by the looks of things, it makes the string URL friendly and readable to the human eye.  However, it I would like to see if it is possible to simplify or "tightened it up" a bit... as I feel my code is probably over complicated.

It is not so much that I want it put onto one line, because I could do that by nesting the functions into one another, but I feel that there might be an overall simpler way of achieving it - I am looking for ideas.

In summary, the code achieves the following:

- Removes any "strange" characters and replaces them with a space
- Replaces any spaces with a dash to make it URL friendly
- Returns a string without any spaces, with words separated with dashes and has no trailing spaces or dashes
- String is readable (Doesn't contain percentage signs and + symbols like simply using `urlencode()`

Thanks for your help!

### Potential Solutions

I found out whilst writing this that article, that I am looking for what is known as a URL 'slug' and they are indeed useful for SEO.

[I found this library on Google code](https://code.google.com/p/php-slugs/) which [appears to work well in the first instance](http://tehplayground.com/#J59T7LABf).

There is also a notable question on this on [SO which can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305879/automatic-clean-and-seo-friendly-url-slugs), which has other examples.

Comment: Just found out that they are called "slugs".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to play with preg like you did. However it gets more and more complicated when you start looking at foreign languages.
What I ended up doing was simply trimming the title, and using urlencode

```
$url_slug = urlencode($title);
```

Also I had to add those:

```
$title = str_replace('/','',$title); //Apache doesn't like this character even encoded
$title = str_replace('\\','',$title); //Apache doesn't like this character even encoded
```

There are also 3rd party libraries such as: http://cubiq.org/the-perfect-php-clean-url-generator

Comment: [Doesn't return a string that is readable](http://tehplayground.com/#e7SykpUcs) - Please read the question?

Comment: Liking the look of that 3rd party library. Have you use it before, did it cause the same problems that you are mentioning?

Comment: I did not use the 3rd party, because foreign language was a very important part for me. I chose to stick to URLEncode, even though it doesn't always look as pretty, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you can do that:

```
$original_name = ' How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python with-dash?';

$result = preg_replace('~[^a-z0-9]++~i', '-', $original_name);
$result = trim($result, '-');
```

To deal with other alphabets you can use this pattern instead:

```
~\P{Xan}++~u
```

or

```
~[^\pL\pN]++~u
```